Prove that $\log \tau(n) = O(\log n / \log \log n)$ as $n \to \infty$ using the hint
Denote by $\tau(n)$ the number of divisors of a positive integer $n$. Recall that if $n = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_t^{k_t}$, where $p_1, \dots, p_t$ are distinct primes and $k_1, \dots, k_t$ are positive integers, then $\tau(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{t} (k_i + 1)$.
(a) Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. Prove that $\tau(n) \leq 2 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \right)^{\pi(2^{1/\varepsilon})} \cdot n^\varepsilon$.
(b) Prove that $\log \tau(n) = O(\log n / \log \log n)$ as $n \to \infty$.
Hint: Apply (a) and choose for $\varepsilon$ an appropriate decreasing function of $n$.
I have already solved (a), but I am having trouble with (b), I tried choosing 1/n, log n, but they don't help me get to what I want, besides I have trouble interpreting the big O, I guess it means that I have to find $|log \tau(n) |\le M(\log n / \log \log n)$ , for some constant M. Any idea?

Your interpretation of $O$ is sufficient for this problem (although you don't need absolute value bars on the logarithm).

@MichaelBurr ok, thanks, I was following the wikipedia page, but I guess that is because $\tau(n)\ge1$.  Any idea about what decreasing function of n works?

Since $\log[(\varepsilon^{-1})^{\pi(2^{\varepsilon^{-1}})}]=\pi(2^{\varepsilon^{-1}})\log\varepsilon^{-1}=O(\varepsilon2^{\varepsilon^{-1}}\log\varepsilon^{-1})$, we have
$$
\log\tau(n)\le C\cdot2^{\varepsilon^{-1}}+\varepsilon\log n+\log2.
$$
Let $\varepsilon=A/\log\log n$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\log\tau(n)
&\le C\cdot\exp\{A^{-1}\log2\cdot(\log\log n)\}+{A\log n\over\log\log n}+\log 2 \\
&=C(\log n)^{A^{-1}\log2}+{A\log n\over\log\log n}+\log 2
\end{aligned}
Choose $A>\log2$, so we have
$$
\log \tau(n)=O\left(\log n\over\log\log n\right).
$$

How did you get this $\pi(2^{\varepsilon^{-1}})\log\varepsilon^{-1}=O(\varepsilon2^{\varepsilon^{-1}}\log\varepsilon^{-1})$ ?

and how does taking  $A>log 2$ makes thes first and last terms go away?

The second term is increasing significantly faster than all other terms.
